# Encodage with french dump

Tags: xml, mediawiki, wikipedia

I have a problem with my French dump of Wikipedia using XML dump.  I'm having a problem with accented characters.

When i install Mediawiki, I choose innoBdb, this my MySQL configuration:

> Enter password:
>   Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
>   Your MySQL connection id is 179
>   Server version: 5.5.8-log MySQL Community Server (GPL)
>   mysql > status
>   c:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.5.8/bin/mysql.exe  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.8, for Win32 (
>   x86)

```
Connection id:          179
Current database:
Current user:           root@localhost
SSL:                    Not in use
Using delimiter:        ;
Server version:         5.5.8-log MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Protocol version:       10
Connection:             localhost via TCP/IP
Server characterset:    latin1
Db     characterset:    latin1
Client characterset:    cp850
Conn.  characterset:    cp850
TCP port:               3306
Uptime:                 3 hours 47 min 6 sec
Threads:                8
Questions:              35648
Slow queries:           3
Opens:                  976
Flush tables:           1  Open
tables:                 50  
Queries per second avg: 2.616
```

I'm using Mwdumper,this my code for the command

```
set class=mwdumper.jar;driver_mysql.jar
set data="frwikis_fr.xml"

java -client -classpath %class% org.mediawiki.dumper.Dumper "--output=mysql://127.0.0.1/my_wiki?user=root&password=" "--format=sql:1.5" %data%
--default-character-set=utf8
pause
```

The tranfert to sql database is good, but the accented characters are not good when I try to retrieve articles.  What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Ok Coool.The problem was really the encodage.I changed the script of my bat file:

```
set class=mwdumper.jar;driver_mysql.jar
set data="frwikis_fr.xml"

java -client -classpath %class% org.mediawiki.dumper.Dumper "--output=mysql://127.0.0.1/my_wiki?user=root&password=" "--format=sql:1.5" %data%
--default-character-set=utf8
pause
```

to

```
set class=mwdumper.jar;driver_mysql.jar
set data="frwikis_fr.xml"
"–default-character-set=utf8"
java -client -classpath %class% org.mediawiki.dumper.Dumper  "--output=mysql://127.0.0.1/my_wiki?user=root&password=&characterEncoding=UTF-8"  "--format=sql:1.5" %data%

added:&characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

pause

Tank's for the 9 persons who unless see my question.lol

Comment: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:MWDumper#A_note_on_character_encoding I guess.
Better example this way probably https://www.mediawiki.org/w/index.php?title=Manual:MWDumper&diff=845958&oldid=845955